# How to avert the save MessageBox prompt in Excel-VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a problem here if you look at my codes below after I call the `.close` line which was the file I initially copied from. It will prompt a save MessageBox message either yes, no, or cancel. Is there anyway I can avoid this save message from appearing programmatic if no was the case could I just programmatic program it `no` instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jon is right to suggest Application.DisplayAlerts
and if you want to answer no to a save as you suggest

```
 Workbooks(Filename1).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the Application.DisplayAlerts to false, then closing.  I recommend turning it back on after setting it.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC:

```
Workbooks(FileName1).Save
```

If you save it explicitly, it won't have to ask you.