# VBA workbooks.Close without being prompted to if the user wants to save?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA program that converts `.xls` files into `.csv` files. The problem is that is brings up the `"Do you want to save the changes to myFile.csv?"` Dialog box.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
currentBook.SaveAs Filename:=fileNameS, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges    
currentBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

What do I need to add so that I don't get the "Do you want to save the changes to `myFile.csv`?" Dialog box?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [How to avert the save MessageBox prompt in Excel-VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824816/how-to-avert-the-save-messagebox-prompt-in-excel-vba) and should therefore be closed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, the method in that post does not work for me.

Comment: Why Dont you try "DoCmd.SetWarnings False"

Comment: @power: They *both* don't work?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, Alistair Weir's solution works. I had to use `currentBook.Saved = True`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True`

```
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        currentBook.SaveAs Filename:=fileNameS, FileFormat:=xlCSV, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        currentBook.Saved = True            
        currentBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done in the past and it's worked for me:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileNameS, FileFormat:=xlCSV, conflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

You can also try putting the Close before the DisplayAlerts is reset to true...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett True, except that my answer was posted before Alistair Weir's. I was referring to a similar answer that has since been deleted.

Comment: Are you implying that you can't see the future? No, seriously, point taken, my apologies!