# using vba to close messagebox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a for loop in VBA to open a series of files.
If the given file is already open, a message box will appear asking if I want to save the file.
How do I select "dont save" without specifying file names in my code?
I do not want to specify file names because they change through each iteration of the for loop
Thank you

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11220537/2258

Comment: showing code is always beneficial

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the alerts by putting this line before the `Workbook.Open` method:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Be sure to turn on the alerts back by adding this after `Workbook.Open` method:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```