# Unable to close excel without showing prompt

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I have a winform application and I am trying to close excel without showing the save prompt. After looking for solutions on google and stackoverflow this is what I have come up with but its not working for me.

```
string filepath = string.Empty;
                string reportname = lblreportname.Text;
                filepath = Application.StartupPath + "\\StandardReports\\" + reportname + ".xls";

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                List<string> WorksheetList = new List<string>();

                xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(lsvSelectedQ.SelectedItem.ToString());

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objRange = null;

                objRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5];
                string intrvl = objRange.Value.ToString();

//more code 

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                xlWorkBook.Save();
                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
                xlApp.Quit();
```

With `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;` i am able to suppress the prompt but I am also unable to close the excel. I can still see the excel process in the task manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA workbooks.Close without being prompted to if the user wants to save?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220537/vba-workbooks-close-without-being-prompted-to-if-the-user-wants-to-save)

Comment: @AxelKemper I am looking for a C# solution. Or a Vb solution that can be easily translated into C# using online tools. The post you referred to has vba solution.

Comment: Have you tried removing second `DisplayAlerts` part? I do `DisplayAlerts=false`, `Save()`, `Close()` and `Quit()` and it works fine for me

Comment: @uteist I tried DisplayAlerts=False but it is popping up save as prompt upon quitting.

Comment: Just map the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11222418/1911064) to C# one-to-one and you should be done.

Comment: Try `xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False);` after saving it first.

Comment: Give me a minute. I'll post the code I use when I go back to my desk.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

To

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

Parameters for xlApp.Workbooks.Open()

```
Workbook Open(string Filename, object UpdateLinks, object ReadOnly, object Format, object Password, object WriteResPassword, object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, object Origin, object Delimiter, object Editable, object Notify, object Converter, object AddToMru, object Local, object CorruptLoad);
```

Comment: this code was giving me error that the excel can not be saved because is in open in read only mode , so passed false for read only while opening the excel. Its not giving me any errors but it is also not closing the excel process in the task manager.

Comment: Well, @Arbaaz because you haven't posted the actual exception in your first, which you should have, I tested it myself and, as you mentioned in the comment above, that the exception is `Additional information: Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only.` which makes perfect sense as you `.Open()` the Excel document in read-only mode! Change first `true` to `false` while `.Open()`ing the document. I'll update the answer accordingly..

Comment: I am not blaming you for missing readonly part. As already mentioned in my comment I found that I need to set readonly to false and I did. But it still did not remove excel process from taskmanager. I have however found another way to solve my problem. But I appreciate your effort.