# Excel cell reference from closed workbook using file name in cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a central location that contains 96 xls files; each of these 96 files represent an individual test located here:

"\server5\Operations\MainBoard testing central location DO NOT REMOVE or RENAME"

I created an Excel workbook to input all the information of each individual test on to a single sheet. Then, I used a VBA to pull the names of the files and add a link to the file on a second sheet on the same workbook. I linked those files to sheet 1.

Next, I added all the information on the top row corresponding to the test performed broken down in to a single line per workbook (Test).

Now I need to populate sheet 1 on the new workbook (Advanced Main board test log.xlsx)

So far this formula works, but only for open workbooks:

```
=INDIRECT("'\\server5\Operations\MainBoard testing central location DO NOT REMOVE or RENAME\["&A7&"]Summary'!$E9")
```

Where A7 represents the column of filenames which ranges from A6 to A103

Summary E9 is the cell I would like to enter in cell C7

[Excel capture of C7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRNzJ.jpg)

Please note the populated values, this is because I have those 2 work books open, All #REF! cells contain the same formula as the populated cells.

please let me know if you need any additional information to accomplish this tedious task

I also tried doing Microsoft recommended method:

```
='[20160613 1002257 35000010-01B.xls]Summary'!$E9
```

replaced file name with cell containing file name:

```
='["&A7&"]Summary'!$E9
```

and I get #REF! in the cell and formula bar automatically changes to:

```
='(\\server5\Operations\MainBoard testing central location DO NOT REMOVE or RENAME\["&A7&"]Summary'!$E9
```

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/how-to-referencing-value-in-closed-excel-workbook-by-formula-incl-variable-shee

Comment: *so far this formula works but only for open workbooks* - if you open the closed workbooks, does it work for them then?

Comment: yes it does work only when open but as soon as you close it and the workbook refreshes the values disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft, the Indirect() function must have the workbook opened. You could cycle through the directory with VBA to get the cell values using this route.

Got a UDF and below is how you'd add it:

- Open Visual Basic editor in excel (Development tab of the Ribbon - you may need to go into Excel options to unhide it).
- Right click VBA Project([Your workbookname]), highlight insert and then click module.
- Paste the below in module1 and save the workbook as a .xlsm.

Code:

```
Function GetField(Path As String, WorksheetName As String, CellRange As String) As Variant

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = GetObject(Path)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    Set rng = ws.Range(CellRange)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Saved = True            
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```

You can then use =GetField() in this workbook only.

Parameters:
=getfield("\server5\Operations\MainBoard testing central location DO NOT REMOVE or RENAME\"&A6,"Summary","E9")

Only tested with one file, but you should be able to use cell references, filenames, etc in rows/columns for more than one.

-Confirmed this works on multiple Rows/Columns

Edit: Changed how workbooks are closed from some code provided by [Alistair Weir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220537/vba-workbooks-close-without-being-prompted-to-if-the-user-wants-to-save) in another issue.

Comment: as soon as you close the source workbooks and the destination workbook refreshes the values disappear. I would write a VBA but my skills are on lvl 1/10

Comment: @Kevin I suggest you add that there is a function called INDIRECT.EXT in morefunc.xll or a UDF macro called PULL that will do what OP asks.

Comment: Correct, once it leaves memory Indirect() will calculate again since it is volatile. I'm thinking of a simple UDF function you can use rather than a larger loop.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have tried installing INDIRECT.EXT but havent had any luck with that either, I have Excel 2016

Comment: @Allan, added a function and instructions on how you can add it and use it.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for advice, wouldn't want to leave Allan out to dry on this :)

Comment: Plus one from me. @Allan you should accept the answer with the button left of Kevins answer

Comment: @Kevin Thank you! I will try this and let you know how it goes!! :-)

Comment: so technically speaking after proceeding with the steps and code you provided, each cell that needs to be populated should have something like this? 
=Getfield("'\\server5\Operations\testing\["&A6&"]Summary'!$E9")
where in active workbook contains the file name, and Summary E9 is the cell to extract from provided file name on A6.

Comment: It would be `=GetField("\\server5\Operations\testing\"&A6,"Summary","E9")`, where A6 is ThisFile.xlsx

Comment: Hello @Kevin, Just FIY it seems like this piece of code opens all reffered workbooks copy and paste but it does not close them. they still open in the back ground.
Tried adding "SaveChanges:=False" to the end of wb.Close but that didn't work either... any clues?

Comment: @AllanPtacnik Try the edited code. They *should* be closing but recalculations could be causing this.

Comment: @Kevin For some reason, This did not work either way, workbooks don't get closed and cells get 0.000