# Excel refuses to close when "Save when Close" Prompt is disabled

Tags: vba, excel, save

I have an Excel file, `PlannerTool` which keeps prompting to save the file when closing, even when it has been saved 2 seconds ago. This is probably due to some volatile code. So I thought I would disable the prompt when the file had been saved within a certain time window. However when I do so, Excel refuses to completely shutdown. It will close the workbook, but a grey screen will remain. See screenshot below.
[image: Grey screen that remains after closing the workbook]

The code I use to deny the prompt is taken from

> [VBA workbooks.Close without being prompted to if the user wants to save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220537/vba-workbooks-close-without-being-prompted-to-if-the-user-wants-to-save)

Complete code used provided below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim SaveTime As Date
Dim CurrentTime As Date
Dim TimeDifference As Long
SaveTime = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
CurrentTime = Now

TimeDifference = DateDiff("s", SaveTime, CurrentTime)
'Gets the time difference between closing and saving in seconds

If TimeDifference <= 10 Then             'Saved less than 10 seconds ago so deny prompt
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'Code gotten from StackOverflow Question
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="PlannerTool", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True            'Tweaked to fit saving format needs
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True    

End Sub
```

If the VB Editor is open when closing the workbook, the editor will remain open and display the `RibbonX_Code` Module. The VBA project containing the workbook `PlannerTool` and code are no longer displayed in the Project Tree, indicating that they are indeed closed. No difference when I have 1 or multiple workbooks opened, these stay displayed in the tree when I close `PlannerTool`. Can anyone tell me why Excel won't close properly?

Comment: What is `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs `good for. Why would you need a SaveAs?

Comment: @Storax Just took it from the original code. Saves the file again, just to be sure that any minute differences that could have occured within the time window are saved. Tested when the line is removed, the error still happens.

Comment: I'd try commenting out the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and see if you're suppressing a dialog that needs to be responded to.

Comment: @Comintern Just tried it. It does prompt an alert, saying that the file with that name already exists. However, clicking "Yes" to the replace the existing file will continue to save it and then the same problem occurs. Same thing when you want to save under a different name.

Comment: Also add Application.enablevents like DisplayAlerts in the code accordingly

Comment: @Storax thx, good addition. put it in and edited the question.

Comment: @Davesexcel But I do not want to close excel completely every time. When I'm working from multiple Workbooks I and I specifically want PlannerTool to close, I don't want to close all my files.

Comment: Completely unrelated observation, but wouldn't you also want to update the stored `BuiltinDocumentProperties` inside the `If` statement?

Comment: @Comintern Why yes. Yes I would like that :) thanks for the addition, completely missed that one. Updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate this behavior locally, and it appears that calling `ThisWorkbook.Close` is the issue. If you open a workbook and then use the Excel menu to close it, (File -> Close), it does the same thing as your code. In the "manual" case, Excel holds the application open because you opted not to close *Excel* - just the open workbook.

This should work as intended if you manually check to see if Excel should be closed.

```
If TimeDifference <= 10 Then             'Saved less than 10 seconds ago so deny prompt
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'Code gotten from StackOverflow Question
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="PlannerTool", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True            'Tweaked to fit saving format needs
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If Application.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
        Application.Quit
    End If
End If
```

I'd suggest this rather than forcing the application itself to close, as the user may have other documents open in Excel.

Comment: Just implemented and tested this. While it does close the Workbook properly, using this solution causes to prompt  the "Save before Close" window again. Seeing as this is the prompt I wanted to block in the first place, using this method would defy the purpose of the code :(.

Comment: Implemented and tested. Works likes a charm. Also tested with multiple workbooks opened, no problem what so ever. Thanks a million for your time!